# AC load driving using FET

Tags: load, fet

I want to drive an AC 220 V load(heater) controlled PWM from Microcontroller. I want to use power FETs to load drive upto 2000 Watts. I m not guessing any valuable circuit design. If anyone have any idea to do this, please help me out... thanx for all...

Comment: Why FETs and not a triac?

Comment: Or even back to back SCR's?   For higher power applications, it's tough to beat SCR's on a cost basis, and I really doubt you want to PWM an AC source, I'm thinking you just want plain phase angle control.  Super simple and inexpensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If anyone have any idea to do this, please help me out

You can do this with a triac and opto-couplers: -

[image]

Here's another idea using a 555 timer: -

[image]

Note that this is only good for a few hundred watts - you'd need a more powerful triac and drive interface for 2 kW. The circuit below might give you 1 kW: -

[image]

Looking around at triacs I think the [BTA41](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiI1uWTlODJAhUGeg8KHa6WAtIQFghFMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fweb%2Fen%2Fresource%2Ftechnical%2Fdocument%2Fdatasheet%2FCD00002263.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFVe6KIHyGBPU48uPk3dHP8xVDmbw&sig2=0rrkSTu3zALQ0IQlv6Farg&cad=rja) should be man enough for the job.

Comment: thank you very much dear. I implement this scheme and then tell you about results. thankx

Comment: hi dear, I want to ask 2 questions:
1) can we use triac in parallel more than 1?
2) can we control heater with PWM? (because I heared that time constant of heater is large and cannot be controlled by PWM)

Comment: This sounds like an evolving set of questions so please be aware that my answer addresses your original question. However, in my opinion I'd say yes to your two extra questions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I implemented and tested. this is working fine. thanks a lot!

Comment: @abdulrazzaq I'm pleased for you and, in return, it is customary for you to press the "accept" button located just below the up and down arrows alongside my answer.